# Docusign Connect events won't send for envelopes created using the API

Tags: docusignapi

We set up a custom Connect endpoint in the DocuSign portal but we are having an issue where it only gets events form Envelopes created in the portal.

For Envelopes created using the API, everything "works" (docs are sent out and can be signed etc...) but the events for those are broken. They show up in the logs, but when we click on them for more info it says **"Oops! We had trouble loading your log details. Go ahead and try that again."** Any with that message never make it to the endpoint.

Again - this is only for envelopes created and sent using the API. Envelopes created and sent through the online portal trigger events successfully and our endpoint picks them up.

Here is an example of the JSON we use to create/send the envelope via the API:

```
{  
  "emailSubject":"Subject",
  "emailBlurb":"Blurb",
  "compositeTemplates":[  
    {  
      "serverTemplates":[  
        {  
          "sequence":"1",
          "templateId":"0000-0000-0000"
        }
      ],
      "inlineTemplates":[  
        {  
          "sequence":"1",
          "recipients":{  
            "signers":[  
              {  
                "email":"test@email.com",
                "name":"Test Person",
                "recipientId":"1",
                "roleName":"Signer 1"
              }
            ]
          }
        }
      ]
    },
    {  
      "serverTemplates":[  
        {  
          "sequence":"2",
          "templateId":"1111-1111-1111"
        }
      ],
      "inlineTemplates":[  
        {  
          "sequence":"2",
          "recipients":{  
            "signers":[  
              {  
                "email":"test@email.com",
                "name":"Test Person",
                "recipientId":"1",
                "roleName":"Signer 1"
              }
            ]
          }
        }
      ]
    },
    {  
      "serverTemplates":[  
        {  
          "sequence":"3",
          "templateId":"2222-2222-2222"
        }
      ],
      "inlineTemplates":[  
        {  
          "sequence":"3",
          "recipients":{  
            "signers":[  
              {  
                "email":"test@email.com",
                "name":"Test Person",
                "recipientId":"1",
                "roleName":"Signer 1"
              }
            ]
          }
        }
      ]
    }
  ],
  "status":"sent"
}
```

We've also tried using eventNotification to set events at the Envelope level with the same result. The event shows in the logs but nothing makes it to the endpoint and no information is available when clicking on the event in the log window (same message as above)...
Any ideas?

Comment: Can you please paste your Connect configuration settings snapshot after masking your endpoint? Also can you check failure logs if your messages are going to failure logs

Comment: @AmitKBist Thanks for the response. There are no failure logs. Here is the [Connect configuration](https://ensparkdev.com/connectSettings.png) and when an envelope is created through the portal the logs and events fire as expected: [Docusign from Portal](https://ensparkdev.com/DocusignFromPortal.png) but any envelope created from the API shows in the logs as this: [Docusign from API](https://ensparkdev.com/DocusignFromAPI.png) and they never hit the endpoint or show more info.

Comment: Ah - for anyone else who might encounter this, it's because our templates are set up to have different Role Names but I was setting the same signer for each role. The API let's you do this, but it breaks somewhere along the way because Docusign expects different recipients for different roles. My fix was to change the role names in our templates so they match.

Comment: Can you please add the fix as answer to the post